# warmup emscripten cache for faster builds

Tags: emscripten

A clean install of emscripten will compile programs much slower as it needs to build the cache of system libraries.  It will output lines like this:

```
cache:INFO: generating system library: libc.a... (this will be cached in "/emsdk_portable/.data/cache/wasm/libc.a" for subsequent builds)
```

There is a flag (https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html) called `--clear-cache` however I would like to do the opposite.  I am looking for a command to fill the emscripten cache for all system libraries.  I'm looking to do this so I can capture the output in a docker and then use it for faster CI builds.

Does anybody know of a way I could approach doing this?

Answer (score 3):

***UPDATE:***

The `embuilder.py` tool is responsible for building the emscripten libraries. You can run this to warm up the cache with system libraries:

```sh
embuilder.py build MINIMAL
```

Or, if you're using the `emscripten/emsdk` Docker image, and want to store the cache contents in `/my/own/cache` for persistence, you can run:

```sh
docker run --rm \
    -v /my/own/cache:/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache \
    emscripten/emsdk \
    /emsdk/upstream/emscripten/embuilder.py build MINIMAL
```

You can find more details about the command by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/embuilder.py) or by passing the `--help` flag.

***ORIGINAL ANSWER:***

If you're using the `emscripten/emsdk` Docker image and want the cache to persist across compilations, then you can just use override the container's cache folder with a bind/volume mount:

```sh
cd /my/project/folder
docker run --rm \
    -v $(pwd):/src \
    -v $(pwd)/my_emscripten_cache:/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache \
    emscripten/emsdk \
    make
```

The first time you run this will obviously be slow, but subsequent runs should be able to make use of the cache and run significantly faster.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. Do you know a way to get ALL system libraries however? Maybe I just need a fake make target that compiles and links against everything...

Comment: @portforwardpodcast I've updated my answer to address this.